# Is it possible to change the clocking for an audio codec from Linux (userland or driver)?

Tags: drivers, audio, embedded, clock

I have an i.MX6 evaluation board with an audio codec from Cirrus Logic (WM8958). The board also supports PTP hardware clocking. Is it somehow possible to change the reference frequency for the audio PLL to the PHC from Linux? Is the common clock framework something to look into for this?